# ksoap2 ver. 2.5.2 HttpTransportSE returns null no matter what I try

Tags: android, wcf, ksoap2, httptransportse

Disclaimer: I AM a newbie at Android programming :(
I have seen a similar question posted here, but the solution did not work for me. I AM trying to meet all the criteria for a properly posted question so please bear with me.
I wrote a C# client to test my wcf service (SimpleHTTPTransport) and it works fine over WiFi from a second computer so I know there are no firewall issues. My Android browser can hit http://10.0.0.134:4444/DietService.svc?msdl with no problem. THe service is set for anonymous user, so no login info necessary. I've checked out every possible reference I could find here and elsewhere on the web for 2 days with no help. I'm using ksoap2 2.5.2 and can't get anything to work. I've even tried setting up an Async Task. I've copied allegedly "working" code and still can't get any comm to the wcf service. At this point, I'm totally stumped. Here is my stack trace, code and the variables at the time of transmission:

```
Stack Trace:

 org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:130)
 diet.diet.MainActivity$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:113)
 diet.diet.MainActivity$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:83)
 android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

CODE:

package diet.diet;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import org.ksoap2.*;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.*;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.*;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        private static final Integer TIMEOUT = 60000;
        private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetFoodName";

        private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

        private static final String URL = "http://10.0.0.134:4444/DietService.svc";

        final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IDietService/GetFoodName";

        Button btn_Request;
        TextView tv_Reply;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            btn_Request = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Request);
            btn_Request.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv_Reply = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Reply);

            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv_Reply.setText("Got it");
            new AsyncCaller().execute();
        }
        private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {
            private String resultData;

            ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pdLoading.setMessage("Loading...");
                pdLoading.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                    request.addProperty("id", "7");

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    Log.i("CYBERON", "Check 1");
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    Log.i("CYBERON", "Check 2");

                    HttpTransportSE myHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, TIMEOUT);
                    myHttpTransport.debug = true;
                    try {
                        myHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        StackTraceElement[] stack = e.getStackTrace();
                        String Trace = "";
                        for(StackTraceElement line : stack)
                        {
                            Trace += line.toString();
                            Trace += "\n";
                        }
    //                    Log.i("CYBERON", "Exception caught");
    //                    Log.i("CYBERON", "RESPONSE: " + myHttpTransport.responseDump);
                    }
                    Log.i("CYBERON", "Check 3");
                    SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                    Log.i("CYBERON", "Check 4");

                    //to get the data
                    resultData = result.toString();
                    // 0 is the first object of data
                    Log.i("CYBERON", "Check 5");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("CYBERON", e.getMessage());
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                pdLoading.dismiss();
                tv_Reply.setText(resultData);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I can find when I break on myHttpTransport.call:

```
this = {MainActivity$AsyncCaller@4404} 
params = {Void[0]@4412} 
request = {SoapObject@4413} "GetFoodName{id=7; }"
 name = {String@4439} "GetFoodName"
 namespace = {String@4440} "http://tempuri.org/"
 properties = {Vector@4441}  size = 1
 attributes = {Vector@4442}  size = 0
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4392} "class org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1920603187
envelope = {SoapSerializationEnvelope@4414} 
 addAdornments = true
 classToQName = {Hashtable@4429}  size = 5
 dotNet = true
 idMap = {Hashtable@4430}  size = 0
 implicitTypes = false
 multiRef = null
 properties = {Hashtable@4431}  size = 0
 qNameToClass = {Hashtable@4432}  size = 5
 bodyIn = null
 bodyOut = {SoapObject@4413} "GetFoodName{id=7; }"
  name = {String@4439} "GetFoodName"
  namespace = {String@4440} "http://tempuri.org/"
  properties = {Vector@4441}  size = 1
  attributes = {Vector@4442}  size = 0
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4392} "class org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -1920603187
 enc = {String@4433} "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  count = 41
  hashCode = -891961955
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@3919} "class java.lang.String"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -1900538580
 encodingStyle = null
 env = {String@4434} "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  count = 41
  hashCode = -1487983936
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@3919} "class java.lang.String"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -2032362507
 headerIn = null
 headerOut = null
 version = 110
 xsd = {String@4435} "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xsi = {String@4436} "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4395} "class org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1922298750
myHttpTransport = {HttpTransportSE@4415} 
 connection = null
 debug = true
 requestDump = null
 responseDump = null
 timeout = 60000
 url = {String@4426} "http://10.0.0.134:4444/DietService.svc"
  count = 38
  hashCode = -193616475
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@3919} "class java.lang.String"
   accessFlags = 8912913
   classLoader = null
   classSize = 666
   clinitThreadId = 967
   componentType = null
   dexCache = {DexCache@4508} 
   dexCacheStrings = {String[41837]@4509} 
   dexClassDefIndex = 1399
   dexTypeIndex = 1366
   directMethods = 1877705544
   iFields = 1875422136
   ifTable = {Object[6]@4510} 
   name = {String@4473} "java.lang.String"
   numDirectMethods = 39
   numInstanceFields = 2
   numReferenceInstanceFields = 0
   numReferenceStaticFields = 2
   numStaticFields = 4
   numVirtualMethods = 55
   objectSize = 0
   primitiveType = 131072
   referenceInstanceOffsets = 0
   sFields = 1875422072
   status = 10
   superClass = {Class@2987} "class java.lang.Object"
   verifyErrorClass = null
   virtualMethods = 1877707104
   vtable = null
   shadow$_klass_ = {Class@735} "class java.lang.Class"
   shadow$_monitor_ = 1263145082
  shadow$_monitor_ = -1984993388
 xmlVersionTag = {String@4427} ""
  count = 0
  hashCode = 0
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@3919} "class java.lang.String"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -2067490254
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4403} "class org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -2124603501
myHttpTransport.debug = true
```

Answer (score 0):

What a learning experience! In searching for more answers, I found that there was a newer ksoap2 library (2.6.0) so I decided to upgrade from 2.5.2.. When I did, I noticed that I was using the 2.5.2 WITHOUT dependencies. After upgrading, my stack trace was much more detailed and indicated a permissions fault. A quick search on the 'net had me check for

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

DUH! I forgot to add it to my AndroidManifest.xml file. Bingo! Connection established. Now all I had to deal with was a contract mismatch. That required adding IDietService to the **SOAP_ACTION** path:

changed:

```
final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetFoodName";
```

to:

```
final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IDietService/GetFoodName";
```

Using the WITH-DEPENDENCIES version of the ksoap2 library was the key to the solution. I don't know if the version upgrade helped.
I admit that I was confused when my catch block found a null for the e.getMessage() when using the ksoap2 2.5.2 but I *assumed* (yea, I know) that that was just the way it was. Bottom line -

CHECK YOUR DETAILS!